# How to capture checkbox checked items in a dynamic list

Tags: asp-classic

I'm generating a list of projects to select from a database.

```
<form action="GetUs.asp" method="post">
<%
Do Until Rs.EOF
%>
<tr>
<td>
    <input name="ShowProjects" type="checkbox" value="<%=Rs("proj_id")%>" />&nbsp;<%=Rs("proj_id")%>
</td>
</tr>
<%
Rs.MoveNext
Loop
</form>
```

The list can be exhaustive. How can I capture only the checked items in the list?

I have

```
response.write Request.Form("ShowProjects")
```

in the called GetUs.asp page,   but that simply returns me every checkbox.

Thanks.

Comment: as far as i know only checked checkboxes are posted? so what do you really want?

Answer (score 0):

change

```
<%
Do Until Rs.EOF
%>
<tr>
<td>
    <input name="ShowProjects" type="checkbox" value="<%=Rs("proj_id")%>" />&nbsp;<%=Rs("proj_id")%>
</td>
</tr>
<%
Rs.MoveNext
Loop
</form>
```

to

```
<%
intX = 1
Do Until Rs.EOF
%>
<tr>
<td>
    <input name="ShowProjects<%=intX%>" type="checkbox" value="<%=Rs("proj_id")%>" />&nbsp;<%=Rs("proj_id")%>
</td>
</tr>
<%
intX = intX + 1
Rs.MoveNext
Loop
</form>
```

change

```
response.write Request.Form("ShowProjects")
```

to

```
response.write Request.Form("ShowProjects1") & ";" & Request.Form("ShowProjects2") ... as many elements you have ...
```

Comment: OK. Got it. Thanks.

Seems a simple Request.Form("ShowProjects") does the trick.

Comment: just because you have FEE elements with the same name, that is why it looks like "Trick", but it's feature ;)